# Regex pattern to match switch statements C++

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to write a regex pattern to be used in a bash script which checks for the syntax of `switch` statements (C++).

The syntax for `switch` statements which I want to follow is the following one.

```
switch(expression)
{
   case constant-expression:
       statement(s);
       break; // must be present
   case constant-expression:
       statement(s);
       break; // must be present

   ....
   ....

   default :  // must be present
       statement(s);
       break; // must be present
}
```

Please note that even though the `break` and `default` statements are not a must, I wish to check for their presence.

I have written this regex pattern to match switch blocks.

`switch(.*?)\n(\s)*?{(\n(.*?))*?(\n(\s)*case(.*?):?(\n(.*?))*?break;)+(\n(.*?))*?\n(\s)*(default:)?(\n(\s)*)*(break|return(.*?))?;(\n(\s)*(.*?))*}`

It successfully matches switch blocks but the problem is that it matches the `switch` blocks **even if the break and default statements are missing**. I tried using `+` operator with the `break` and `default` words but they don't seem to work.

**EDIT UPDATE:**

Is it possible to match switch blocks such as the following one using a parser?

```
switch (PC_INT[address.port][address.pin]) 
    {
    #if defined (__AVR_ATmega2560__) || defined(__AVR_AT90CAN128__)
        case EINT_0:
            // Mask the interrupt so it doesn't fire anymore, i.e put a zero in the mask register.
            EIMSK &= ~(1 << INT0);
            break;
        case EINT_1:
            EIMSK &= ~(1 << INT1);
            break;
            ....
        default:
            return GPIO_INT_OUT_OF_RANGE;

    #elif defined(__AVR_ATmega64M1__) || defined(__AVR_ATmega64C1__)
        case EINT_0:
            // Mask the interrupt so it doesn't fire anymore, i.e put a zero in the mask register.
            EIMSK &= ~(1 << INT0);
            break;
        case EINT_1:
            EIMSK &= ~(1 << INT1);
            break;
            ....    
        default:
            return GPIO_INT_OUT_OF_RANGE;
    #else
        #error "GPIO interrupts not implemented for this configuration."
    #endif
    }
```

Comment: Regular expressions cannot match real or even greatly simplified C++ syntax.

Answer (score 4):

Non-greedy patterns (like `.*?`) are not magic.

You apparently expect the `.*?` in `(\<case:.*?\<break;\s*)+` (a simplified form of your regex) to not match `case:`. Why wouldn't it? In other words, the text:

```
case 1:
  do_something();
case 2:
  do_something_else();
  break;
```

certainly matches `case.*?break;`; the `.*?` matches `1: do_something(); case 2: do_something_else();`.

`.*?` isn't a fence, either. `case.*?break(more)` might not match the first `break` following the `case`, if `(more)` doesn't match the text following the first `break` but does match the text following the second one.

As for the `default:` apparently being optional, that's precisely what your regex says:

```
(default:)?
```

I don't think the regex is salvageable. You can't parse C or C++ with regexes.

You really need to use a better parsing infrastructure. You could build a simple parser using `flex` and `bison` which would work for source code which doesn't play games with the preprocessor, but you might be better off using a real C++ parsing library, like `libclang`.